# How did the US approval ratings in the Middle East change over the last two decades?

Tags: united-states, middle-east

How did the US approval ratings in the Middle East change over the last two decades? Did US approval ratings go down, did they stay the same or did they rise?

Answer (score 4):

[Pew Global Indicators](http://www.pewglobal.org/database/indicator/1/group/6/)  only goes back 14 years, so a 20 year estimate is no quite possible, but it comes close to estimating the question you ask. Using their data, yields the this image:

[image: Graph of Middle East Attitudes about the U.S. Over Time]

A cursory analysis of the countries for which we have the best data shows that in Lebanon and Israel the attitude has improved slighty, in Egypt it has gotten worse, and in Jordan and Turkey the trend is about the same. There is a lot of noise, however, so the data could be different with a different time span.

On balance it looks as if the U.S.' reputation in the area is generally poor, and that reputation is mostly stable within, but not across countries.